# Error 521 Ray ID: 48d542ef727ac1a9 • 2018-12-22 20:15:36 UTC

Tags: magento-1.9

Suddenly without making any changes in the setup, I am getting stuck at 
checkout/onepage
when checking the response of that page in console, I am getting this:

```
Error 521 Ray ID: 48d5b5ffc61f23ea • 2018-12-22 21:34:10 UTC
Web server is down
You
Browser
Working
Ashburn
Cloudflare
Working
magentopatchupdate.com
Host
Error
What happened?

The web server is not returning a connection. As a result, the web page is not displaying.
What can I do?
If you are a visitor of this website:

Please try again in a few minutes.
If you are the owner of this website:

Contact your hosting provider letting them know your web server is not responding. Additional troubleshooting information.

Cloudflare Ray ID: 48d5b5ffc61f23ea • Your IP: myserver-ip • Performance & security by Cloudflare
```

Not able to makeout, what this error is about, anyone having faced this issue, can throw some lite, as where to fix the same.

No cloudflare service is being used by the site.

The response I am getting is against the request to this url
`mysite/checkout/onepage/saveOrder/form_key/ivatVdDpZSe8m3ax/`

Comment: `magentopatchupdate.com` - looks like something in your store is doing check on that domain.

Comment: Thanks that was it. I used the grep to find the string and it was included in a `app/code/local/ ... Observer` so I just moved the same to bak file.